# Get exact folder structure of embedded resources

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5

I'm embedding a whole folder of files as embedded resources in my project. Build actions are set to **Embedded Resource**, not plain **Resource**, and I didn't include those files in project resource list in properties. However, when I try to get their full names using `GetManifestResourceNames`, I end up with a full path delimited with a period, for example:

```
MyApp.Resources.Folder.Subfolder.file.dat
MyApp.Resources.Folder.Subfolder.file2.dat
...
```

Bad news: folder structure may vary, and it may contain folders named like `Folder1.00` or `Folder/file1.xml.backup`
Thus, I can't distinguish when a file name is `Folder.Ext/file.old.xml`, and when it's `Folder/Ext/file/old.xml` and so on.

I dunno what to do. Prebuild folder structure to some filelist and parse it at runtime? That will be a whole mess. Maybe there's a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Have you created files with expected duplicate paths and checked what happens? I'd be curious what happens if both `Folder.Ext/file.old.xml` and `Folder/Ext/file/old.xml` exist together.

Comment: @WillEddins It just won't compile in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really needing to know the folder structures, you'll just have to keep things predictable.

If you ensure that there are no periods in folder names and file names will only have 1 period, then you can safely parse your resource string into it's appropriate `<namespace>.<path>.<filename>` heirarchy.

It depends on your requirements as well. If you just want all subfolders with `Folder1`, the rest of the folder structure parsing no longer matters as it's just matching the beginning resource string. Anything more complex, you will likely need to save the hierarchy information (perhaps generated in a build phase) in a format meaningful to you.

Comment: yeah, I thought the same thing, but hoped that there can be another way... perhaps, not.